# Table of Product Representations of Functions?

Tags: analysis, functions, reference-request

Does anyone know where I could find a (preferably free, online) table with infinite product expansions of basic functions (e.g. trig functions, logarithms, special functions)? Specifically Weierstrass/Hadamard factorizations?

Thanks :)

Comment: Probably a complex analysis textbook. Try Knopp, "Weierstrass's Factor Theorem", Theorem of Functions, vol II; Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis,;Boas, Entire Functions; Conway, Functions of One Complex Variable

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman Thanks for the reply. I was more looking for a free online source. Ill edit my post to reflect this.